# Attempting to receive a list of tuples but somewhat confused

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples

I'm busy making my way through an MIT opencourseware paper and have become somewhat stuck on a certain problem.

The problem involves solving a Caesar Cipher that has multiple levels of encryption through shifting at different points in the text multiple times.

The code I've written solves these shifts and returns the positions and shift number that needs to be given to decipher a Caesar shifted text.

The function should return a list of tuples of the locations of where the shift begins from and the shift number. At the moment all I'm getting is the following:

(([12, 11], [3, 9]), [0, 21])

Any help would be appreciated cheers.

```
def find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, text, start)

    for shift in xrange(27):
        ## Begin shifting the text along the segments you would like to see shifted while holding constant the text that is not to change.
        s = text[:start] + apply_shift(text[start:],shift)
        print s
        letter_position = start
        for letter in s[start:]:
            if letter == " " and is_word(wordlist,s[start:letter_position]):
                start = letter_position + 1
            letter_position += 1
        if is_word(wordlist,s[start:len(s)]):
            print "Base Case"
            shifts += (begin,shift)
            return shifts
        elif start != begin:
            print "Recursion"
            shifts += (begin,shift)
            return find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist,s,start), shifts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the last line of your code

```
return find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist,s,start), shifts
```

The issue is `find_best_shifts_rec` should be returning a `list` of `tuples`, but you are making a `tuple` out of this result. This can be fixed by changing the line to:

```
return find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist,s,start) + shifts
```

This will concatenate the `list` of `tuples` returned by `find_best_shifts_rec` to the `list` of `tuples` in `shifts`.

Comment: Ahh, so much time spent on this and that was my problem. Thank you very much. 

The only other change I had to make was to change:

`shifts += (begin,shift)`

to 

`shifts += [(begin,shift)]`